# can someone help me with Table.Select(Expression) where expression could be something like this Expression = "id in (1,2,3,4)"

Tags: c#, datatable.select

Is there an example of `Table.Select(Expression)` where expression could be something like this:

`Expression = "id in (1,2,3,4)"`

I have a list if ids in a variable `IdList`.
Table contains all the `TS_Ids` where as the `IdList` only has subset of the ids. 
So I want something like this

```
        string IdList = "(1,2,3,4)";
       Table.Select("[ts_id] in IdList");
```

Comment: Please surround your code snippets with ` marks.

Comment: I tried that but it returned me empty datatable

Comment: do you know of any sample that I can refer to. I cannot seem to find a direct sample anywhere for the in clause. (Linq)

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTable.Select method uses the [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. And the IN operator is listed between the allowed operators in the Expression property. So your code could be written as

```
DataRow[] rows = Table.Select("[ts_id] in (" + IdList + ")");
```

Of course this assumes that your IdList variable contains a valid string of Ids separated by commas. something like

```
IdList = "1,3,5,6";
```

If you want a DataTable as return value then you could write

```
DataRow[] rows = Table.Select("[ts_id] in (" + IdList + ")");
if(rows.Length > 0)
{
   DataTable subTable = rows.CopyToDataTable();
   ......
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it is returning me empty table. Table has 3 columns and one of it is `TS_ID`. If I I give it like `DataRow[] rows = Table.Select("[ts_id] = 1");` then it works. But the `"in"` doesnot return anything.

Comment: Strange, I have just tested it and a sample returns just the rows requested. Check the parenthesys and the content of your IdList.